# Correctly suppress comments

Tags: pyparsing

I want to filter out comments starting with a hash # out of a text file, before I run a larger parser over it.

For this I make use of suppress as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835663/how-to-treat-prefixed-keywords).

pythonStyleComment does not work, because it ignores quotations and removes stuff within it. A hash in a quoted string is not a comment. It is part of the string and therefore should be preserved.

Here is my pytest which I already implemented to test the expected behavior.

```
def test_filter_comment():
    teststrings = [
        '# this is comment', 'Option "sadsadlsad#this is not a comment"'
    ]
    expected = ['', 'Option "sadsadlsad#this is not a comment"']

    for i, teststring in enumerate(teststrings):
        result = filter_comments.transformString(teststring)
        assert result == expected[i]
```

My current implementation breaks somewhere in pyparsing. I probably do something which was not intended:

```
filter_comments = Regex(r"#.*")
filter_comments = filter_comments.suppress()
filter_comments = filter_comments.ignore(QuotedString)
```

fails with:

```
*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py:4480: in ignore
    super(ParseElementEnhance, self).ignore(other)
*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py:2489: in ignore
    self.ignoreExprs.append(Suppress(other.copy()))
E   TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Any help how to ignore comments correctly, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I was so close. I have of course to properly instantiate the QuotedString class.The following works as expected:

```
filter_comments = Regex(r"#.*")
filter_comments = filter_comments.suppress()
qs = QuotedString('"') | QuotedString("'")
filter_comments = filter_comments.ignore(qs)
```

Here are some more tests.

```
def test_filter_comment():
    teststrings = [
        '# this is comment', 'Option "sadsadlsad#this is not a comment"',
        "Option 'sadsadlsad#this is not a comment'",
        "Option 'sadsadlsad'#this is a comment"
    ]
    expected = [
        '', 'Option "sadsadlsad#this is not a comment"',
        "Option 'sadsadlsad#this is not a comment'",
        "Option 'sadsadlsad'"
    ]

    for i, teststring in enumerate(teststrings):
        result = filter_comments.transformString(teststring)
        assert result == expected[i]
```

Comment: Glad you were able to work this out! As an aside, you can iterate over both your test strings and your expected strings using Python's `zip`: `for teststring, expectedstring in zip(teststrings, expected): ... assert result == expectedstring`. Equivalent with using `enumerate`, but I find using iterators to be a little neater-looking than indexing with `[i]`.

Comment: @PaulMcG Yes, thank you. I have changed that in my test. I am wondering though, why is ignore QuotedStrings not the default behavior of pythonStyleComment?

Comment: Some of the higher-level builtins like `commaSeparatedList` and `nestedExpr` *do* trap internally for quoted strings to avoid the common pitfall of commas or parens inside quotes. But the built-in comment expressions have many possible applications beyond just `transformString`, so I leave the larger concept of what should or should not be ignored when looking for them to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're using is not correct.

I think you meant:

```
^\#.*
```

or

```
^(?:.*)\#.*
```